# Why is setState inside useEffect not re-rendering the component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I've got the list working; the delete button does delete the items from the database; for some unknown reason the useEffect that triggers the deletion isn't re-rendering the component. Here is my mess:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { Container, ItemDescription, ProductContainer } from "./style";
import api from "../../api";
const API = "http://localhost:4000/select";

interface DATA {
  sku: string,
  name: string, 
  price: string,
  type: string,
  size: number,
  weight: number,
  height: number,
  width: number,
  length: number,
}

interface IProps {
  del: boolean
}

const ProductDisplay = ({del}:IProps) => {
  const [productList, setProductList] = useState<Array<DATA>>([]);
  const [checkedItems, setCheckedItems] = useState<Array<boolean>>([]);
  const [deleteList, setDeleteList] = useState<Array<any>>([]);
  const renderBlock = useRef(0) // will change this to a boolean after I don't have to deal with react's strict mode anymore
  const [reRender, setReRender] = useState(false); //only here as a state to change with useEffect
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async (data: any) => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(data);
        const results = await response.json();
        setProductList(results);
        
        const checked = new Array(results.length).fill(false);
        setCheckedItems(checked);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    };
    fetchData(API);
  }, []);
  
  
  const handleOnChange = (position:number) => {
    const updatedCheckedItems = checkedItems.map((item, index) =>
      index === position ? !item : item
    );
    
    setCheckedItems(updatedCheckedItems);
    
    let skuList = updatedCheckedItems.map(
      (currentState, index) => {
        if (currentState === true) {
          return productList[index].sku;
        }
      }
    );

    const cleanList = skuList.filter( Boolean );
    cleanList.forEach(queryReady)
    function queryReady(item:any, index:number, arr:any) {
      arr[index] = `sku=${item}`;
    }
    
    setDeleteList(cleanList)     
  };
    
  useEffect(() => {
    if(renderBlock.current === 2) { 
      api.delete(`/delete?${deleteList.join("&")}`).then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data)
      }).catch((error) => {
          console.log(error)
        });
      setReRender(!reRender); //figured this should trigger a re-render... it doesn't.
    };
    renderBlock.current = renderBlock.current + 1; //just the janky strict mode workaround
  }, [del]);
  
  return (
    <div>
      {productList.length === 0 && <h4>Fetching Checkboxes ...</h4>}
      {productList.length > 0 &&
        <Container>
          {productList.map((item: any, index) => (
            <ProductContainer>              
              <input type="checkbox"
                value={item.sku}
                id={`custom-checkbox-${index}`}
                checked={checkedItems[index]}
                onChange={() => handleOnChange(index)}
              />
              <ItemDescription>
                <span className="sku" >{item.sku}</span>
                <span className="name" >{item.name}</span>
                <span className="price" >{item.price} $</span>
                {item.size && <span className="size" >Size: {item.size}MB</span>}
                {item.weight && <span className="weight" >Weight: {item.weight}KG</span>}
                {item.height && <span className="dimention" >Dimention: {item.height} x {item.width} x {item.length}</span>}
              </ItemDescription>
            </ProductContainer>
          ))}
        </Container>  
      }
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductDisplay;
```

I am getting "del" from a parent through props (delete button in the header component).

Pretty sure a local reload would get it working, but wanted to avoid that.
I'm also in this to learn, so don't want a solution that leaves me wondering what was wrong.

Thanks in advance for any time, effort and patience you put into helping me with this!

After comment edit:

This is my parent component:

```js
import ListHeader from "../components/headers/list_header";
import ProductDisplay from "../components/product_display";
import Footer from "../components/footer";
import { Container } from "./styles";
import { useState } from "react";

function ProductList(): JSX.Element {
    const [del, setDel] = useState(false);
    return (
        <Container>
            <ListHeader 
                del={del} 
                setDel={setDel} 
            />
            <ProductDisplay 
                del={del} 
                setDel={setDel} 
            />
            <Footer />
        </Container>
    )
}

export default ProductList;
```

and this is the header component:

```js
import { AddButton, ButtonContainer, Container, DeleteButton, TitleContainer } from "./style";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

interface IProps {
    del: boolean
    setDel: (del: boolean) => void
}

function ListHeader({del, setDel}: IProps){
    return (
        <Container>
            <TitleContainer>
                <h1>
                    Product List
                </h1>
            </TitleContainer>
            <ButtonContainer>
                <Link to='/add-product'>
                    <AddButton>
                        ADD
                    </AddButton>
                </Link>
                <DeleteButton id="delete-product-btn" onClick={() => setDel(!del)}>
                    MASS DELETE
                </DeleteButton>
            </ButtonContainer>
        </Container>
    )
}

export default ListHeader;
```

I sent the setDel to the productDisplay component to use it instead of setReRender... no changes.

Comment: Is the value for `del` changing? That is the only value you have in the dependency array so if that is never changing, this component will never re-render. Is `del` being passed down correctly from the parent? You are setting `setReRender(!reRender);` but you aren't doing anything with reRender. Just setting it in the useEffect wont cause it to re-render. The useEffect hook will only re-render when a dependency value has changed inside the dependency array. If the del prop is being passed down correctly and the delete actoin is working, then you could change del to deleteList as the dependency

Comment: I recommend reading [Updating state based on the previous state](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state). As `reRender` isn't a `useEffect` dependency, your `setReRender(!reRender)` won't work as you expect.

Comment: Tried adding reRender to the dependencies and nothing. Also tried using setDel(!del) inside the useEffect hook and nothing. Console log catches the change from the button click but nothing changes after the setDel command in the hook.